# Microprofile REST client providers not active if in separate jar file

Tags: cdi, rest-client, microprofile

I'd like to use some Microprofile REST client, injected with `@RestClient`, in different war files.

I need to register a `javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter` for basic authentication.
If this filter is in my war project, it works fine (for example with `org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.annotation.RegisterProvider` like `@RegisterProvider(AuthFilter.class)`. Curiously if the AuthFilter class is in an external jar file, it doesn't work any more : the filter is not active.

My question is : how to register a filter outside my war project ? I don't want to have this filter repeated in every project that uses my REST API client.

PS : I use wildfly 25.0.1.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without examining your entire codebase, but I do have a guess: Do you have a `/META-INF/beans.xml` file in the compiled jar? Depending on the CDI specification level you are using, that is probably required.

If you're building using maven, you should put this file in `src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml` relative to the project root.

Here is an example of a beans.xml JEE v8:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="annotated"
    version="2.0">
</beans>
```

And here is a reference for all current CDI versions: https://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/cdi/configuring-beans-xml-file

The other guess I have is that since this is a filter class, you probably *also* need a web fragment file in the same folder.

Here is an example web-fragment.xml for the same JEE v8 specification level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-fragment
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">
</web-fragment>
```

And here is a guide to other versions: https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/

Comment: That's right, you need beans.xml in the jar AND in the war file.